# if statement condition not working for last i in the loop

Tags: python

I wrote for loop to calculate the probability for conditional entropy but if the statement is not working correctly for the last i in the loop.

The array I am trying to iterate through:

```
joint_age_dia = np.c[data["Ageover50"],data["diabetic"]]
joint_age_dia
array([['True', 'yes'],
       ['False', 'yes'],
       ['False', 'no'],
       ['True', 'yes'],
       ['True', 'no'],
       ['True', 'yes'],
       ['False', 'no'],
       ['False', 'no'],
       ['True', 'yes'],
       ['False', 'no']], dtype=object)
```

The for loop that I create to get the counts of (Y|X=True), (Y|X=False) is

```
for i in range(len(joint_age_dia)):
  if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'yes' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'True':
    yy_t += 1

  if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'yes' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'False':
    yy_f += 1

  if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'no' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'True':
    yn_t += 1

  if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'no' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'False':
    yn_f += 1

  else:
    None

print(yy_t) # 4
print(yy_f) # 1
print(yn_t) # 2
print(yn_f) # 3
```

If the loop works correctly yn_t is supposed to be 1 and yn_f should be 4 but I noticed when i = 10 it counts the last list of the array wrong (Since it's 'no' when the left side element is 'False', yn_f should have been incremented).

I can't figure out what went wrong...

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(len(collection))`. Prefer `for item in collection` and iterate over them directly. If you _absolutely_ need the indices for some reason, use `for i, item in enumerate(collection)`.

Comment: You show results of print(yy-t) but your code sample doesn't include the print statement.  Also, yy_t is not initialized in your code, please include complete code sample.

Comment: Using `yy_t, yy_f, yn_t, yn_f = 0, 0, 0, 0` as initial values I was unable to reproduce the issue and voted to close.

Comment: I initialised the array to the values you show and I got 4, 1, 2, 4 not the erroneous 3 you mention.

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. Is I initialize the four variables with zero, I get the correct answer of 4 1 1 4. I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: It looks like an initialization issue from the other comments. Code looks correct to me. For debugging / style purposes, I'd also recommend adding some prints during the for loop, replacing all but the first `if` with `elif`, and throwing a ValueError in place of the `None`.

Comment: I got 4,1,1,4. An advice: you should modify the for loop to`for val in joint_age_dia` and substitute every `joint_age_dia[i]` with `val`. Also use `elif` instead of the last three `if`s and `pass` instead of `None`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have a numpy array, use a vectorial solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(joint_age_dia).value_counts()
print(df)
```

output:

```
0      1  
False  no     4
True   yes    4
False  yes    1
True   no     1
dtype: int64
```

Or as dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(joint_age_dia).value_counts().to_dict()
```

output:

```
{('False', 'no'): 4,
 ('True', 'yes'): 4,
 ('False', 'yes'): 1,
 ('True', 'no'): 1}
```

If **really**, you need variables:

```
yy_t, yy_f, yn_t, yn_f = (
 pd.DataFrame(joint_age_dia).value_counts()
   .reindex([('True', 'yes'), ('False', 'yes'), ('True', 'no'), ('False', 'no')])
)

print(yy_t, yy_f, yn_t, yn_f)
# (4, 1, 1, 4)
```

But this becomes a bit ugly IMO

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I would just avoid this whole problem entirely. Consider:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = [['True', 'yes'],
...      ['False', 'yes'],
...      ['False', 'no'],
...      ['True', 'yes'],
...      ['True', 'no'],
...      ['True', 'yes'],
...      ['False', 'no'],
...      ['False', 'no'],
...      ['True', 'yes'],
...      ['False', 'no']]
>>> Counter(tuple(i) for i in d) # Have to use tuple because Counter uses a dict 
>>>                              # under the hood and keys have to be hashable.
Counter({('True', 'yes'): 4, ('False', 'no'): 4, ('False', 'yes'): 1, ('True', 'no'): 1})
```

We're skipping having to make a bunch of conditional checks, so the code is easier to read, and you can trust that it always consumes everything in whatever your collection is because we don't have silly `range(len())` stuff happening.

Answer (score 1):

This Works fine, refer to comments from
Jan Christoph Terasa,  yy_t=0, yy_f=0, yn_t=0, yn_f=0

```
joint_age_dia = [['True', 'yes'],
                         ['False', 'yes'],
                         ['False', 'no'],
                         ['True', 'yes'],
                         ['True', 'no'],
                         ['True', 'yes'],
                         ['False', 'no'],
                         ['False', 'no'],
                         ['True', 'yes'],
                         ['False', 'no']]
        yy_t=0
        yy_f=0
        yn_t=0
        yn_f=0
        for i in range(len(joint_age_dia)):
            if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'yes' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'True':
                yy_t += 1
    
            if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'yes' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'False':
                yy_f += 1
    
            if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'no' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'True':
                yn_t += 1
    
            if joint_age_dia[i][1] == 'no' and joint_age_dia[i][0] == 'False':
                yn_f += 1
    
            else:
                None
        print(yy_t)  # 4
        print(yy_f)  # 1
        print(yn_t)  # 1
        print(yn_f)  # 4
```